# JQuery UI smoothing out column animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a table with the option to expand/retract a column.  Using JQuery UI Toggle slide i have it so it 'slides' in and out.  However it's not a very smooth transition and looks pretty bad when the buttons clicked.

Here's the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LhsS4/

This is a basic version of what i'm using, and even in this you can see some stuttering, this becomes even more apparent when you add table borders on.

Here is the JQ

```
$(function () {
    $('.toggleoff').hide;
    $('.newtoggle').on('click', function () {
        $('.toggleoff').toggle("drop", 250);
    });
});
```

Here's the HTML

```
<button class ="newtoggle" alt="Expand"> Click me </button>     

<table id="tblMainData" class="tablesorter">
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                          <th>1</th>
                          <th>2</th>
                          <th>3</th>
                          <th>4</th>
                          <th>5</th>
                          <th>6</th>
                          <th class="toggleoff">7</th>
                          <th>8</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                       <tr>
                          <td>a</td>
                          <td>b</td>
                          <td>c</td>
                          <td>d</td>
                          <td>e</td>
                          <td>f</td>
                          <td class="toggleoff">g</td>
                          <td>h</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                          <td>i</td>
                          <td>j</td>
                          <td>k</td>
                          <td>l</td>
                          <td>m</td>
                          <td>n</td>
                          <td class="toggleoff">o</td>
                          <td>p</td>
                       </tr>       
        </tbody>
                 </table>
```

I've tried adjusting the speed of the transition but this still doesn't fix it.  I think the main problem is when it's toggled the table data field borders don't slide in, they appear in a skewed way until the data stops.  Is there any way of smoothing it out?

Comment: this is because you are hiding `<td>`. i will behave perfect for divs.

Comment: Yeah i figured as much - i have similar operations on large div sections which work fine, i was hoping there'd be some clever workaround to load the borders or something after the text maybe

Comment: What i ended up doing was instead of sliding or just toggling appear was use 'FadeIn', it looks much more natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in general jquery-ui does a much better job at animations.
http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/

If you add the jQuery UI to your code you'll get a much nicer effect than using the standard jQuery toggle function.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a fiddler of what it looks like:
http://jsfiddle.net/LhsS4/10/

And in general I'd try and avoid a table for layout, Tables are out (unless you're sending it in email in which case tables for layouts are the way to go).
If you need tables try using the display property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/tables/

Good Luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i was using Jquery UI already, looks like there's not much i can do about it other than making them just 'appear', not ideal but better than witnessing those hideous animations.  I've never used a CSS table (thinking HTML is structure and CSS is style) but i'll have to look into it!  Thanks